# Fetching all contacts in ios Swift with all keys?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

I am aware of the ios swift has a Contacts Framework where I can fetch contacts, but I cannot find any method to fetch all the contacts together where I can access each of the contacts from that array. All methods for fetching contacts seems to require some sort of conditions. Is there any method where I can get all the contacts together with all keys?

Thanks

Comment: Guys please comment if you are really know the answer, The above links are clearly saying to fetch certain key from a contact.  Could you please help me out with exact solution to fetch all contacts with all keys. Thanks

Comment: @TusharSharma. I know search on google. There is no specific post regarding fetching all contacts with all keys by default. without any predicates.  I will appreciate if you can provide any such links.